# Setup notification Channel, currently not working

Tags: android, notifications

I created an app for testing notifications using the alarmmanager. It works on devices that don't use the notification channel.

I am trying to add a channel for android 8.0 but I don't seem to get it.

Can someone help sort this out so I can receive the notification on devices with Android 8.0+

ActivityMain

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final Context context = this;

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setReminder(context,ReminderReceiver.class,10);
            Snackbar.make(view, "Hope", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void setReminder(Context context, Class<?> cls, int sec)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
    intent.putExtra("TIME",sec);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, sec, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);/* Find more about flags: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent */

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (sec * 1000), pendingIntent );//Add time in milliseconds. if you want to minute or hour mutiply by 60.. For ex: You want to trigger 5 Min then here you need to change 5 * 60 * 1000


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

ReminderReciever

```
public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int Request_Code = intent.getExtras().getInt("TIME",0);
    showNotification(context, MainActivity.class,
            "New Notification Alert..!", "scheduled for " + Request_Code + " seconds",Request_Code);
}

public void showNotification(Context context, Class<?> cls, String title, String content,int RequestCode)
{
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            RequestCode,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"Default");
    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String channelId = "id1";
        CharSequence channelName = "id1";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    //assert notificationManager != null;
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(RequestCode,notification);
}

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".ReminderReceiver"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add setChannel(notificationChannel) in the notification Builder, like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"Default");
Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(content).setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(alarmSound).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setChannel(channelId).build();
```

Add this code after you create a notification channel.